# How can I schedule tasks efficiently?

Tags: algorithm, scheduled-tasks

I have a problem at work that I simply cannot figure out.
A collection of tasks needs to be scheduled for execution. Each task has an interval (validStart and validEnd) during which it can be executed. On top of that, users can submit tasks in real time and the system needs to schedule them accordingly.

How do I even begin to do that?

I considered an approach where I:

- build lists of tasks that do not overlap
- keep some sort of queue of these lists where worker threads can retrieve a set of tasks and execute them

But this doesn't exactly work if new tasks are constantly being submitted by users.

The entire solution also needs to be reliable.
I could not find a library or something that I can at least adapt to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the multiple assignment segment tree structure to solve this problem. When you add a new task with the id number with the interval [a, b], assign the id value to the tree elements on the segment [a, b]. Now, when you want to know which task to perform at time i, ask the tree for the sum on the segment [i;i] - this is the number of the task that can be performed at time i.